# Adding icon to top right of android home-screen

Tags: android

Im trying to make my application show an icon to the top right, next to the clock and battery-icon, [like this](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1372/androidemulator.jpg).

I am unable to find any documentation on this issue. If it is undocumented, i.e. "API can be changed at any time", then I dont think I will use it. But otherwise, it would be very neat to indicate that my service is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done.

You can, however, add an icon at the top-left in the notification area.
Just create a `Notification` with the [`FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT) flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can (at least in Android 4.3)
(I know it's an old post but just in case someone still is wondering...)
1 - Create an icon (eg my_notif_icon.png, using File/New/Other/Android/Android Icon Set in eclipse)
2 - In your Service Activity, add a constant (eg MyServicenotifId) to be able to remove your notification icon when your service is killed:

```
private static final int MyServicenotifId = 1;
```

3 - Add the necessary imports:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

4 - In your onStartCommand method create the notification builder and manager:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_notif_icon);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert");
mBuilder.setContentText("Detailed Notification");
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(MyServicenotifId, mBuilder.build());
```

That should show the icon when you launch the service.
To remove the icon when the service is killed add these lines in your service onDestroy method:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(GLiBnotificationID);
```